# Display a React.js component only when all Redux-Form fields have value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, redux-form

I would like to display a React JSX component only if I have all the Redux-Form fields containing some value, how do I achieve this?

I don't want type multiple empty tests field-by-field.

Same in pseudo code:

```
{hasAllFields(form) && <p>You're all set!</p>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the props you have the Object `fields` which contains all the information of the fields that you need.

But, as per documentation and live validation, you have to evaluate the values of the fields individually.